# How to handle "open in" retrieved file with swift 2

Tags: swift, pdf, content-type

I'm trying to build a quite simple app which uploads files to our server using standard http requests.

I'd like the app to be some sort of hub being able to open an email attachement for example.
That worked out, I added the info to the info.plist.

Now that file is sent to my app successfully (eg a pdf file)...

How can I retrieve that file url to display it for example in a webview ? I googled for hours, seems to fo through the appDelegate but I have no idea how that continues...

Just found this code, now I'm stucked (and don't even know if that actually works !)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: url)

    return true

}
```

Any help to point me in the right direction is highly appreciated ! I started using swift 5 days ago, please be gentle ;)

Comment: So you are trying to open a PDF for viewing in a UIWebView, correct? Is this file on the device or your server?

Comment: Neither, its coming from another app (so probably on the device but not my apps local storage).

Comment: When you open a pdf in your emails you can choose "open in". I then select my app and that's the point where I'm stuck right now !

Comment: Aaaah. Ok, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but it appears that what you want to do is this:

1. Go to your project settings
   [image: target selection]
2. Go to the "info" tab
3. Under "Document Types" add the document types you want to support
4. To get the added file, you need to look in the `Documents/Inbox` folder for your app, as shown below:

```
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let inboxPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Inbox")
do {
    let dirFiles = try filemgr.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(inboxPath)
} catch {
    //Handle error
}
```

I am not certain what exactly gets passed to `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`, but it might help in checking which file was opened.

Additionally, straight from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html):

> Use this directory to access files that your app was asked to open by outside entities. Specifically, the Mail program places email attachments associated with your app in this directory. Document interaction controllers may also place files in it.
>
> Your app can read and delete files in this directory but cannot create new files or write to existing files. If the user tries to edit a file in this directory, your app must silently move it out of the directory before making any changes.

This answer adapted from [this tutorial](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/03/04/associate-a-file-type-with-your-ios-application.aspx) ([part 2](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/03/05/ios-tips-and-tricks-associate-a-file-type-with-your-app-part-2.aspx) & [part 3](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/03/15/ios-tips-and-tricks-associate-a-file-type-with-your-app-part-3.aspx))